# How do I merge rows with one similar cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Chinese words in Cell A, and an example sentence for that word in cell B. In cell A there are duplicates of the same word, but with different example sentences. For duplicate words I want to put the sentences all on one line.

Example:

```
Cell A - Cell B

Bob - Example sentence for Bob.
Cat - Example sentence for Cat
Bob - Another example sentence for Bob
```

I want this to end up like this:

```
Cell A - Cell B - Cell C

Bob - Example sentence for Bob. - Another example sentence for Bob.
Cat - Example sentence for Cat
```

There is going to be more than just two of the same words, so sentences will also go on D, E, F, etc.

I've looked through past posts and tried some of the suggestions there, but I couldn't get anything to work for what I'm specifically trying to do.

This is a picture for more clarity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/onTPX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I can think of would be to;
-Group or sort by column A. 
-Then copy the relevant range from column B.
-And paste special 'transpose' into column C.

A little manual I know. A less accurate way might be to use the VLOOKUP function. But this will only give the first match.